# hide two elements on click on anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to hide two elements with classes `notify-me` and `write-review`, on click on anywhere on the page but not on those two elements.

How to do this using prototype?

Right now if I click on even the overlays, they are being closed.

PS: I am attaching the click event to `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var re = /(^|\s)(notify-me|write-preview)(\s|$)/;
    if (re.test($(e.target).classNames())) return false;
    $$('.notify-me', '.write-preview').invoke('hide');
});
```

Here is an improved version which bubbles up through the target element's ancestors :

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var re, els, iterator;
    re = /(^|\s)(notify-me|write-preview)(\s|$)/;
    els = [$(e.target)].concat($(e.target).ancestors());
    iterator = function (el) { return re.test(el.classNames()); };
    if (els.find(iterator)) return false;
    $$('.notify-me', '.write-preview').invoke('hide');
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/U7E2a/.

Comment: oops.. yup this worked like charm.. was in stress.. so didn't accepted at that time :).. Thanks